# Ajax call to call jsp

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I have a html file. On submission of form i need to call a jsp & jsp should return any boolean value to the calling html page.

Please suggest the code.

Thanks in advance
Tanu

Actually i m working on contactus form. There is an html page for UI form.and on submit of this form it should call a jsp which should return on that html.Because if i will call jsp then on every refresh it will send an email which i dont want.

Please suggest.

Comment: Sorry. But did you try to google after "calling jsp from jquery"?

Comment: You should show what you've tried so far and explain why it didn't work as you expected. We're not here to do your work for you; we're here to help you figure out how to do it yourself and help you learn things you can use in the future. "Please suggest the code" doesn't show any effort on your part.

Answer (score 1):

Actually we can't write your full code but we can try to help you when you have a problem. A good starting point for you could be [here](http://www.hiteshagrawal.com/ajax/ajax-programming-with-jsp-and-servlets) and i also suggest you use [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) to ease cross-browser problem for AJAX requests

Answer (score 1):

Here Html page will look like this

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function loadXMLDoc()
{
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","ajax_info.jsp",true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="myDiv"><h2>Let AJAX change this text</h2></div>
<button type="button" onclick="loadXMLDoc()">Change Content</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Jsp page will be like this -- ajax_info.jsp

```
<%@ page  language="java" import="java.util.*" errorPage="" %>
<% boolean myInfo = false; %>
<%=""+myInfo%>
```

don't use any html tags in jsp page which is ur calling from ajax.

Comment: Please don't answer non-questions. The asker should demonstrate that they've put at least some effort into solving the problem themselves first. We don't typically answer "plz send me codez" type questions here. Thanks.

Comment: It was quite useful for me, since I was wondering if it can work with jsp as well as it does with php. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would not call a JSP when using AJAX since JSP are best suited for viewing purposes (i.e. rendering HTML, or XML).

I would suggest you using a plain servlet. [Here's a simple tutorial on how to use AJAX with plain Servlets](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-ajax1/).

If you still want to call JSP with your AJAX request you can still do that. Just point your AJAX request to your proper JSP URL.